# How to read this part of the web XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

I am working on a XML reader which shows the result in the labels.
I want to read the node called "Opmerking" which is standing in "Opmerkingen"
A example:

```
<VertrekkendeTrein>
 <RitNummer>4085</RitNummer>
 <VertrekTijd>2014-06-13T22:00:00+0200</VertrekTijd>
 <EindBestemming>Rotterdam Centraal</EindBestemming>
 <TreinSoort>Sprinter</TreinSoort>
 <RouteTekst>A'dam Sloterdijk, Amsterdam C., Duivendrecht</RouteTekst> 
 <Vervoerder>NS</Vervoerder>
 <VertrekSpoor wijziging="false">4</VertrekSpoor>
 <Opmerkingen>
  <Opmerking> Rijdt vandaag niet</Opmerking>
 </Opmerkingen>
</VertrekkendeTrein>
```

"Opmerkingen" is not always there, it is always changing.  The code i use now:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ActueleVertrekTijden/VertrekkendeTrein/*");
```

and:

```
foreach (XmlNode nodelist2 in nodeList)
{
    if (i < 17) //4
    {
        switch (nodelist2.Name)
        {
            case "VertrekTijd": string kuttijd4 = (nodelist2.InnerText);
            var res4 = Regex.Match(kuttijd4, @"\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}").Value;
            lblv4.Text = Convert.ToString(res4); break;
            case "TreinSoort": lblts4.Text = (nodelist2.InnerText); break;
            case "RouteTekst": lblvia4.Text = (nodelist2.InnerText); break;
            case "VertrekSpoor": lbls4.Text = (nodelist2.InnerText); i++; break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can i read the part "Opmerking" and set it in a case?
I tried it a few times, but it failed.
 i also tried:

```
case "Opmerking": var texeliseeneiland1 = (nodelist2.InnerText); if (texeliseeneiland1 == null) { } else { lblop1.Text = texeliseeneiland1; lblop1.Font = new Font(lblop1.Font.FontFamily, 17); lblop1.Visible = true; picop1.Visible = true; }; break;
```

Anyone who knows the answer?

Comment: have you tried a google search on how to read XMLNode..?

Comment: Perhaps something like this will work for you in your `xmlDoc.SelectNodes(@"//ActueleVertrekTijden/VertrekkendeTrein");`

Comment: Its quite simple with [XDocument](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J3Gcvb)

Answer (score 1):

Just extend your logic with check whether current node has child nodes and if so, read them and process:

```
if (nodelist2.HasChildNodes)
{
  for (int i=0; i<nodelist2.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
  {
    var childNode = root.ChildNodes[i];
    //do whatever you need to display the contents of the child node. 
  }
}
```

Also I have to recommend to consider LinqToXML or at least refactor the code you shared. With LinqToXML is might be as easy as this:

```
var temp = from remarkNode in nodelist2.Descendants("Opmerking")
           select remarkNode.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow load the xml content in an XDocument object and loop through it.
Example: read it from a file

```
 var doc = XDocument.Load("C:/test.xml");

 foreach (var xe in doc.Descendants("Opmerking"))
 {
     var value = xe.Value;
     //Do your job with value
 }
```